# Magento memory Limit for admin report

Tags: php, magento-enterprise, database, memory

I have a question while I were trying to get report (customer by number of order purchase) from magento admin, I got the memory limit error when tried to pull report for last 6 month and I selected "*yearly*" option from "*show by dropdown*".

I checked the memory limit and found `512M`, so I changed it to `1G`.

Now for last `6 month` there is no problem but when I tried to pull report for last `1 year` there is again memory limit issue.

I can extend the memory limit but is it really needed? like is there any problem with magento set up because if I will extend it to `2G` then it will create problem for last `2 years`, so extending memory limit is not seem to be a solution.

Please let me know if is there anything which I can do here?

Comment: Iterating over huge collections takes more memory. Limit the returned data to only what you need to reduce memory requirements.

Comment: That mean I have to override Magento core report class because this problem is coming with Magento core reports, there is no custom code.

Comment: Welcome to the Magento resource hog. The more successful you are, the larger your database grows, the more resources Magento consumes.